# JSP compilation error when using auto-boxing

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, autoboxing

Getting below error while executing below JSP content in Tomcat 7.0.54

```
<%
    Object one =  new Long(1);
    Long value = Boolean.TRUE ? (Long)one : -1l;
%>
```

Error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:348)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Any pointer to the cause of the problem will help me to understand the problem better.  It seems jsp is getting compiled to .class file successfully but during runtime i am getting this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%
    Object one =  new Long(1);
    Long value = (Boolean.TRUE ? (Long)one : -1l);
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The suggested solution didn't seems to be working. I have modified it another way to make it work. It seems to be problem with this tomcat version. I tested the same with tomcat 7.0.61 there is no diff between generated java file in work directory. In tomcat 7.0.54 it is throwing error but in tomcat 7.0.61 working perfectly. Whats the role of tomcat in evaluating conditional expression ? I want to understand this bug.

Answer (score 1):

The `-1l` is not `Long` object it is primitive data `long` try this:

```
<%
    Object one =  new Long(1);
    Long value = Boolean.TRUE ? (Long)one : new Long(-1);
%>
```

The mentioned code works find when you compile and run the code with JDK, it seems that there may be a bug in tomcat which tries to convert JSP to Java before compile

Comment: Why would OP get a runtime exception?  OP's code will compile just fine.

Comment: @Alireza Fattahi I checked the generated java code.  Its fine and there is no diff between code generated by this tomcat 7.0.54 and tomcat 7.0.61 but still i am getting exception during runtime, while it is working fine in tomcat 7.0.61.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object one =  (long) 1;
Long value = Boolean.TRUE ? (Long)one : -1l;
```

Try preceding code instead of yours

In java following is "Unnecessary boxing to Long"

```
Object one =  new Long(1);
```